# Using std::shared_ptr with clang++ and libstdc++

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, clang, libstdc++

I'm trying to use the std::shared_ptr in clang++(clang version 3.1 (trunk 143100)) using libstdc++(4.6.1). I have a little demo program:

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> some(new int);
    std::shared_ptr<int> other(some);
    return 0;
}
```

which can be build using:

```
clang++ -std=c++0x -o main main.cpp
```

and gives the following error output:

```
main.cpp:6:23: error: call to deleted constructor of 'std::shared_ptr<int>'
    std::shared_ptr<int> other(some);
                         ^     ~~~~
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:93:11: note: function has been explicitly marked
deleted here
class shared_ptr : public __shared_ptr<_Tp>
```

For some reason it needs the constructor which is deleted because a move constructor is provided (which is correct behaviour).
But why does it work compile with (g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1.)? Somebody any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: `/usr/include/c++/4.6` is usually not where G++ looks for its system headers. Try `g++ -v yourfile.cpp` to see G++'s search path.

Comment: @Mat: Is it not? g++ usually looks for c++ standard headers inside `/usr/include/c++/$(version)` AFAIK, so g++4.6 would look in that directory. As of clang++, it probably depends on how it was compiled/configured

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The implicitly-declared copy constructor for shared_ptr is deleted because shared_ptr has a move constructor or a move assignment operator (or both), per C++11 12.8p7:

If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared implicitly. If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4).

GCC 4.6.x does not implement this rule, which came into the C++11 working paper very late in the process as [N3203=10-0193](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3203.htm). The shared_ptr in libstdc++ 4.6.x was correct at the time it was written, but C++11 changed after that.. Boost had [exactly the same issue](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/changeset/73202) with it's shared_ptr, and this is one of the [common incompatibilities](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#deleted-special-func) between GCC and Clang.

Adding a defaulted copy constructor and copy assignment operator to shared_ptr will fix the problem.

Comment: Note: whether the template constructor is usable for copying is not actually relevant to this issue: the implicitly-declared (deleted) copy constructor is a better match than the template constructor.

Comment: That (the note) implies that the compiler will never instantiate a template to generate the copy constructor, does it not? That is, the implicitly declared will always be a better match than any templated constructor, which effectively means that while the standard does not seem to explicitly forbid that template from being used as *copy-constructor*, the fact is that it will never be. Or will it?

Comment: The guys form gcc/libstdc++ added following: shared_ptr(const shared_ptr&) noexcept = default; to std::shared_ptr

Comment: @DougGregor Thanks and thanks! The link you passed from 'svn.boost.org' helped me a lot to solve an issue with Caffe and Ubuntu 12.04. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

The standard library headers for gcc 4.6 seem to be wrong in this case as the standard requires the following constructor (§20.7.2.2.1/16):

```
shared_ptr(const shared_ptr& r) noexcept;
```

Which is a copy-constructor that seem to be missing from the gcc implementation. The implementation I have at hand (g++-4.6.0) offers (in `bits/shared_ptr.h`):

```
template<typename _Tp1>
shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<_Tp1>& __r)
```

But does not have a proper copy-constructor (a templated constructor cannot be used by the compiler as a copy constructor). I find it strange, though, that such an error would come up with a production compiler...

**EDIT** I have been trying to figure out why exactly g++ 4.6 compiles the above code with it's own standard library. It seems that it is picking up the `template`d constructor as a viable overload for copy construction, which made me look back to the standard to verify whether that is a bug --I have always been under the impression that a template could not been used as a copy constructor-- or not.

In the C++03 standard, there is a footnote <sup>106)</sup>

> Because **a template constructor is never a copy constructor**, the presence of such a template does not suppress the implicit declara-
>   tion of a copy constructor. Template constructors participate in overload resolution with other constructors, including copy construc-
>   tors, and a template constructor may be used to copy an object if it provides a better match than other constructors.

That footnote is not present in C++11. Footnotes are not normative, so there has to be other quote supporting that note. A couple of paragraphs below there you can find:

> 12.8/3 A declaration of a constructor for a class X is ill-formed if its first parameter is of type (optionally cv-qualified) X and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments. **A member function template is never instantiated to perform the copy of a class object to an object of its class type.**

The first part of the paragraph means that a constructor cannot take the same type as argument (copy constructors take references, and allowing such constructor would cause an ambiguity, that and the fact that it would require *copying* into the argument, for which the best overload --assuming that this inhibited the copy constructor-- would be the same function, which in turns would require... infinite loop).

The second part of the clause states that a templated constructor cannot be used to create copies of the type, which seems to be the normative section supporting footnote <sup>106)</sup>. Now, that has been carefully reworded in C++11 to state:

> 12.8/6 A declaration of a constructor for a class X is ill-formed if its first parameter is of type (optionally cv-qualified) X and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments. **A member function template is never instantiated to produce such a constructor signature.**

Now, what this means is that the restriction *a template cannot be used to copy* has been removed, and replaced by the less strict restriction: a template will not be instantitated to generate a constructor of the form `S( S )`, i.e. one that would cause an ambiguity with the copy constructor.

With this lesser restriction, it seems that the templated constructor above can actually be used as a *copy-constructor*, as the signature that it generates is compatible. This supports the behavior of the g++ 4.6 compiler when processing the `bits/shared_ptr.h` header, and would imply that `clang++` is failing to use the template as a valid constructor.

Now the next question is whether the standard library implementation shipped with g++4.6 is actually compliant or not. I cannot say off the top of my head. On one side, it is missing the signature of constructor that I mentioned above, so you can argue that it is not compliant. But on the other hand, a compliant compiler should pick up the templated constructor to achieve the same functionality, and the implementation would behave *as-if* that constructor was present.