# boost::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr&)' is implicitly declared as deleted

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    Node(int data, boost::shared_ptr<int> next = boost::make_shared<int>())
      : m_data(data), m_next(next) {}

    int m_data;
    boost::shared_ptr<int> m_next;    
};
```

**Error**: 
http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php
- Compile and Execute C++11 Online (GNU GCC version 4.7.2)

```
Compiling the source code....
$g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1
main.cpp: In constructor 'Node::Node(int, boost::shared_ptr)':
main.cpp:9:34: error: use of deleted function 'boost::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr&)'
In file included from /usr/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17:0,
from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:168:25: note: 'boost::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr&)' is implicitly declared as deleted because 'boost::shared_ptr' declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
```

Question> I have see the post [Using std::shared_ptr with clang++ and libstdc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964360/using-stdshared-ptr-with-clang-and-libstdc). However, I don't know how to fix it.

The solution posted in that question is "Adding a defaulted copy constructor and copy assignment operator to shared_ptr will fix the problem."

Comment: It sounds like you've got a buggy version of Boost. Is it an option to either disable C++11 support, or use `std::shared_ptr` instead?

Answer (score 29):

This is a [bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/changeset/73202) in older versions of `boost::shared_ptr` that makes it incompatible with C++11 compilers.

The final C++11 standard says that declaring a move constructor or move assignment operator prevents the implicit definition of a copy constructor, but older versions of `boost::shared_ptr` do not respect that rule and assume that a copy constructor will be implicitly defined.

You either need to upgrade to Boost version 1.48 or later, or edit the Boost headers to add this to `shared_ptr`:

```
shared_ptr(const shared_ptr&) = default;
```

Comment: At least with boost 1.46.1, you only need to add the copy constructor.  The second line, defining operator=, gives a compile error as boost explicitly defines the assignment operator.

Comment: Updating to Boost 1.48 on Precise resolved the issue for me.  It's in the default system repositories, so you can assume it to be stable.  Without looking at the code, I suspect that 1.48 is the earliest version that has the fix.

Comment: @Elkvis, thanks for that. I just checked the code in the 1.47.0 and 1.48.0 releases and the fix appeared in 1.48.0 so I've updated the answer.