# Code compiles in MSVC and Intel but not GCC 4.8, issue with shared_ptr and push_back

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, g++, shared-ptr

I ported my code from Windows (where it compiles fine with the MSVC and Intel compilers) but when using GCC 4.8.1 (in GCC 4.7 I would get an internal compiler error) I get this nasty error (apologies for size). Can someone please help me?

```
g++ -m64   -c -g -I/usr/include/boost -I/usr/include -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Idx.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Idx.o Idx.cpp
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>; _Args = {const boost::shared_ptr<Stk>&}; _Tp = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/alloc_traits.h:254:4:   required from ‘static typename std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::value, void>::type std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>; _Args = {const boost::shared_ptr<Stk>&}; _Alloc = std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> >; typename std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::value, void>::type = void]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/alloc_traits.h:393:57:   required from ‘static decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>; _Args = {const boost::shared_ptr<Stk>&}; _Alloc = std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> >; decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) = <type error>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:906:34:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>; _Alloc = std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>]’
Idx.cpp:22:35:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::shared_ptr<Stk>::shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr<Stk>&)’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17:0,
                 from Idx.h:10,
                 from Idx.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:168:25: note: ‘boost::shared_ptr<Stk>::shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr<Stk>&)’ is implicitly declared as deleted because ‘boost::shared_ptr<Stk>’ declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
 template<class T> class shared_ptr
                         ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>; _Args = {boost::shared_ptr<Stk>&}]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:53:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*; _ForwardIterator = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:117:41:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*; _ForwardIterator = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:258:63:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*; _ForwardIterator = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*; _Tp = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:209:29:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>; _Alloc = std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> >]’
Idx.cpp:11:23:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::shared_ptr<Stk>::shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr<Stk>&)’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>; _Args = {const boost::shared_ptr<Stk>&}]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:53:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*, std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > >; _ForwardIterator = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:117:41:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*, std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > >; _ForwardIterator = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:258:63:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*, std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > >; _ForwardIterator = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*; _Tp = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:316:32:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>; _Alloc = std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> >]’
Idx.cpp:28:9:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::shared_ptr<Stk>::shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr<Stk>&)’
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::shared_ptr<T>& boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator=(const boost::shared_ptr<T>&) [with T = Stk]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:335:18:   required from ‘static _OI std::__copy_move<false, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = const boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*; _OI = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:390:70:   required from ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = const boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*; _OI = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:428:38:   required from ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*, std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > >; _OI = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*, std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:460:17:   required from ‘_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*, std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > >; _OI = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::shared_ptr<Stk>*, std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:199:63:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = boost::shared_ptr<Stk>; _Alloc = std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> >]’
Idx.cpp:11:23:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:305:9: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::shared_ptr<Stk>::shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr<Stk>&)’
         this_type(r).swap(*this);
```

Here is the header file of the class in question (Idx.h):

```
#ifndef Idx_H
#define Idx_H
#include "Stk.h"

#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Idx
{
    public:
        Idx();
        Idx(string sid);
        Idx(string sid, vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > Idxinstrslist, unordered_map<string,double> Idxwtings);
        ~Idx();

        vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > getIdxinstrsList();
        void addinstrToIdx(boost::shared_ptr<Stk> s, double wting);
        void setIdxinstrsList(vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > indinstrlist);
        double getIdxStkwting(string sid);

    private:
        vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > Idxinstrslist;
        unordered_map<string,double> Idxwtingsdict;
        string sid;
};

#endif
```

and the source (line 22 refers to the vector push_back):

```
#include "Idx.h"

Idx::Idx(){}

Idx::Idx(string id){
    sid = id;
}

Idx::Idx(string id,vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > Idxinstrlist, unordered_map<string,double> Idxwtings){
    sid = id;
    Idxinstrslist = Idxinstrlist;
    Idxwtingsdict = Idxwtings;
}

Idx::~Idx(){}

void Idx::addinstrToIdx(boost::shared_ptr<Stk>  s, double wting){

    string sid = s->getSecurityID();
    if(Idxwtingsdict.count(sid)==0)
    {
        //THINK ITS COMPLAINING ABOUT THIS LINE......................................
        Idxinstrslist.push_back(s);
        Idxwtingsdict[sid] = wting;
    }
}

vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > Idx::getIdxinstrsList(){
    return Idxinstrslist;
}

void Idx::setIdxinstrsList(vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > indinstrlist){
    Idxinstrslist = indinstrlist;
}

double Idx::getIdxStkwting(string sid){
    double wting = 0;

    if(Idxwtingsdict.count(sid) == 1){
        wting = Idxwtingsdict[sid];
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "problem" << endl;
    }

    return wting;
}
```

Comment: You need a newer version of Boost that plays nice with C++11. Ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900730/boostshared-ptrshared-ptrconst-boostshared-ptr-is-implicitly-declared

Comment: @mythagel I'm on 1.48 so you could be right! Do you know how to install 1.53 or 1.54 from the terminal in Linux? libboost all-dev gives me 1.48

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Comment: @user997112 linux distributions vary wildly. It is probably easier to download and build boost locally.