# error: use of deleted function boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator

Tags: c++, boost, g++, deleted-functions

I have this strange error when I try to compile a C++ and qt project:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator::directory_iterator(const boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator&)’
```

There is no delete() used anywhere in the code, what does this error mean? What should I be looking for when this type of error occurs?

Comment: It means the function directory_iterator() has been deleted and you still use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that might be correct, but I'm not using any function directory_iterator(), I have this after the error message:  { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }

Comment: I am facing the same issue but with a different library. How can this be fixed ? /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator::directory_iterator(const boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator&)’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^

Comment: I reinstall everything, I'm not sure if the problem was a missing library or something, because the problem just dissappear, sorry for not give you a precise answer, but that kind of errors are very strange...

Answer (score 1):

It happens if you use `std=c++11` with old libboost like 1.48.

Solution is install new version.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900730/boostshared-ptrshared-ptrconst-boostshared-ptr-is-implicitly-declared) also.