# Clang 4.6.2, use shared_ptr

Tags: c++, clang, shared-ptr, google-nativeclient

From PNaCl, I use libstdc++ to compile same code. But I want use shared_ptr and I obtain this error :

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of
```

This problem have issue :

[Using std::shared_ptr with clang++ and libstdc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964360/using-stdshared-ptr-with-clang-and-libstdc)

I understand, but I don't know how resolve this. I quote the solution :

> Adding a defaulted copy constructor and copy assignment operator to shared_ptr will fix the problem.

I add this in shared_ptr.h:

```
shared_ptr(const shared_ptr&) noexcept = default;
```

But compiler returns now this error :

```
F:/nacl_sdk/pepper_31/toolchain/win_pnacl/usr/include/c++/4.6.2/bits/shared_ptr.
h:268:19: error:
  exception specification of explicitly defaulted copy assignment operator
  does not match the calculated one
  shared_ptr& operator=(const shared_ptr&) noexcept = default;
              ^
```

In this chain of error, I finish here.

Somebody have tips, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to repro your bug with this simple test case:

```
#include <memory>

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<int> foo;
  std::shared_ptr<int> bar(foo);
  std::shared_ptr<int> baz;
  baz = foo;
  return 0;
}
```

Building with `pnacl-clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ test.cc`

The easiest way to fix it it is to use libc++ instead of libstdc++:

`pnacl-clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ test.cc`

This is "experimental" in pepper_31, but will be the default in pepper_33 and higher (which is currently pepper_canary). See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/native-client-discuss/0spfg6O04FM for more info about this switch.

I was also able to hack two headers to make it work with libstdc++:

In bits/shared_ptr.h:

```
template<typename _Tp>
class shared_ptr : public __shared_ptr<_Tp>
{
public:
  shared_ptr(const shared_ptr&) = default;
  shared_ptr& operator =(const shared_ptr&) = default;
  ...
```

In bits/shared_ptr_base.h:

```
template<typename _Tp, _Lock_policy _Lp>
class __shared_ptr
{
public:
  __shared_ptr(const __shared_ptr&) = default;
  __shared_ptr& operator =(const __shared_ptr&) = default;
  ...
```

IMO, using libc++ is a better solution here. :)

Comment: This hack works very good. But with CFLAGS = -std=c++11  -O2 -Wall -stdlib=libc++, I have a lot of errors in a c header files.

Comment: You may want to try -std=gnu++11 instead, it may be that your C headers are using non-standard extensions.

Comment: c header files are in nacl_sdk\pepper_31\toolchain\win_pnacl\usr\include\c++\v1. Is it normal what are non-standard extensions? -std=gnu++11 work only with this hack. If I combine with -stdlib=-stdlib=libc++, I obtain new errors in the link step "undefined reference to std::_1::basic_string...". It is like a infinite loop, then I will stop here and use this helpful hack. Thank for your helps.